# Merging tables that span multiple pages using Camelot

Tags: pdf, extract

I am currently retrieving tables from PDF files using Camelot.  In many instances, one table will span multiple pages or have a blank row.  These two situations lead Camelot to produce two or more tables (depending on how many blank rows there are or how many pages the table spans).  I wonder if there is a way to append those separate tables back into one table after Camelot has produced the multiple tables?  Is there a way to tell Camelot to ignore page breaks and/or blank rows?